# UnsupportedOperationException when trying to save dataframe to redshift

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-redshift

I am working with pyspark and saving dataframe to redshift. I am getting the below error when trying to save it to

```
": java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unexpected type NullType.
        at com.databricks.spark.avro.SchemaConverters$.com$databricks$spark$avro$SchemaConverters$$convertFieldTypeToAvro(SchemaConverters.scala:283)
"
```

When I look athte source code for ScehmaCovnerters : 
https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/databricks/spark/avro/SchemaConverters.scala

I can see no support for NullType. I have columns in dataframe which are null.

What is the solution to this?

Comment: as a workaround, instead of null I am now using empty space

Comment: Can you file an issue at https://github.com/databricks/spark-redshift/issues to report this bug?